# Passing array to another class

Tags: java, arrays

The problem when passing the below array from the Sentence class to the Word class.

```
    public class Sentence {
        private static String[] arrayList = { "Everybody", "was", "having" + "fun" + "at" + "the party" };

        public static String[] getArrayList() {
            return arrayList;
        }
    }

============================
public class Word extends Sentence {
    public void getArayList(String[] a) {
        String[] araylist = Exper.getArrayList();
        for (String s : araylist) {
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Naming String Array as `arrayList`, is very confusing. What is the purpose of `int k = 4;`?

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do here. What do you mean by `trying to transfer the array list from the Sentence class to the Word class`?

Comment: Please understand that when you are sharing code for review/debugging kindly use java naming conventions and best practices. This helps you to get answers quickly.

Comment: 1. I should get the array list created in the Sentence class in the Word class 2. Then I have to change every 4-th letter in every word from the array list into @ (short word like 'at' should be left without changes) this is why I use k = 4; the output should be like Ever@body was havi@g fun at the party

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, making names such as `getArrayList` and `arayList` will just throw off your thought process completely.

Main issue wasn't really your code use, rather than simply not paying attention. Look at `arrayList` below compared to yours, some was concatenated, and 'the party' was one array. in fact the `go` method is redundant here - the String array should be:

`private static String[] arrayList = {"Everybody", "was", "having", "fun", "at", "the", "party"};`

your main method simply needs this: - everything else in your code was functional besides the typos and redundancies.

        `Word word = new Word();
        word.getArayList();`

Comment: 1. I have to get an array list created in the Sentence class in the Word class 2. Then I have to change every 4-th letter in every word from the array list into @ (short word like 'at' should be left without changes) this is why I use k = 4; the output should be like Ever@body was havi@g fun at the party

Comment: Completely revised above